# Multiple child nodes of the same name in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Artist 1</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <artist>Artist 2</artist>
        <artist>Artist 3</artist>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Now in XSLT I want to loop through the child nodes of `<cd>` and check if it is a `<title>` or `<artist>` or `<country>` etc... So far I have done the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="artist">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="country">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="country"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="company">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="company"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="price">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But for some reason `<artist>` is displaying the first one only the others are not displaying. What I want is to display each node in sequence even if there is `<artist>`, `<country>` and another `<artist>`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply removing the `choose` altogether.  An `xsl:choose` stops as soon as it hits the first successful `when` test, essentially you're saying "if there's an `artist` then show that, else if there's a `country` then show that, else ...".

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="country"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="company"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You don't need to check whether or not elements exist before you apply templates; `apply-templates` will process all the nodes that its `select` expression finds, if the `select` finds nothing then `apply-templates` will simply do nothing.

If you want to process the elements in document order rather than first the artists, then the countries, etc. then just group them into one `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="artist | country | company | price | year" />
```

or if you don't want to have to name all the elements explicitly then move the `title` logic into its own template

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

and then your main template can simply be

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Yes it worked like this. But I have a small problem. All of the `<artist>` tags are being grouped. Is there a possible way to display every tag in sequence of how they appeared in the xml file?

Comment: @user2892479, simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>` and then write matching templates, that way the elements are processed in document order.

Comment: So I have to remove `<xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>` and replace it with this: `<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::artist)]"/>` for every child node. Did I understand you well?

Comment: @user2892479 no, Martin's comment is a way to apply templates to all child elements except the ones that are named `title` - you would replace the whole `choose` from your original XSLT with his single `apply-templates`.  Or consider my approach of moving the `title` processing into a template and then you can just apply-templates to `*` unconditionally.

Comment: Ok it's working fine now. I didn't notice that you have edited the answer, I followed your approach and it worked. Thanks a lot